# Importing voce.jar into a java file properly

Tags: java, jar, import, voice-recognition

I have downloaded a voice/text API for java from
http://voce.sourceforge.net/

However being semi new to java I am unsure how to use all these jar files in my code, have tried several things like import voce, import java.voce, package (my folder name with the voce jar inside).

However I am getting no luck.

Code I am trying is

```
import java.voce;
 public class SpeechInterface
 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("hello world"); 

   }
 }
```

Error I get is that it cant find voce(since I am obviously doing this wrong). Have looked through stackoverflow but was unable to find a question that answers this. I imagine there is one like this already but I can not find it. Closest I could find was the importing voce to C, but that wasn't to helpful.

The jar file is in same directory as the java file.

Comment: Are u getting compilation issue..or issues in running ?

Comment: Compile issue from the first line, assuming the import is being done wrong

Comment: If you are using an IDE , mention that ,

Comment: @AdnanAhmadKhan Using dr java IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

import voce.*

If you look at http://voce.sourceforge.net/api/java/_speech_interface_8java-source.html

It mentions the package as (package voce).

Comment: it gives me this error on line 6:Error: cannot access voce.SpeechInterface
  bad source file: C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Lain\voce\SpeechInterface.java
    file does not contain class voce.SpeechInterface
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.

Comment: You need to add the voce JAR fie in the buildpath of your IDE

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pfpcse/java/DrJavaTutorial.html) under the Tab no 10. You can find how to add a Jar file to Dr.Java IDE,

Then as Kakarot Mention , you should to write

```
import.voce.*;
```

if you need all the classes of package voce,
or write

```
 import.voce.classname
```

to import a specific class.